# React Native Android cannot load html file from local

Tags: android, react-native, webview, local-files

I would like to load a local html file in my React Native App. Its works in IOS but failed in Android. Here I my code:-

```
 <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={Platform.OS === 'android' ? { uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' } : require('../screens/index.html')}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          />
```

Here is my local html file path.

[image]

I have no idea where should I configure in order to get it works...Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working. Remember to restart your react server everytime you change in android folder

Comment: Hi @Harpreet, I using expo to compile the app... what should I do ya?

Comment: @Eddy don't have much experience with expo, you can refer this: https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-use-local-html-files-for-webview-in-expo/32421/2
I think there is no need to add html file in android folder in expo, i may be wrong. Let me know the result